# TWIG SLICE -> UT8

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-filter

I want to make an excerpt of an entity resume.

So I do

```
{{ randBook.resume|slice(0, 200) ~ '...'}}
```

It work but i'm french and all of my spécial caracteres are like this #%00 so how I want to convert into UTF-8 ?

And I Try it

```
{{ randBook.resume|striptags|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')|slice(0, 200) ~ '...'}}
```

But it's the same.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What Symfony version are you using?

Comment: @COil I use symfony 4.4